# Print key=value pair on .env file

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

i make .env file with this format

```
consumer_key="value1"
consumer_secret="value2"
```

i try to print out my environment variable,

```
import tweepy
import os
import schedule
import time
import random
from vocab import daftar
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

print(os.environ)
```

it works well on my machine, then i try to upload it in the server and i found this problem when running my phyton file

```
environ({'PYTHONUNBUFFERED': 'true',
'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:', 
'PYTHONHOME': '/app/.heroku/python','LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 
'DYNO': 'run.6602', 'PYTHONHASHSEED': 'random',
'FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS': '*','PWD': '/app', 'DYNO_RAM': '512', 
'value1':'value2',
'_': '/app/.heroku/python/bin/python3'})
```

why the environment variable don't match key=value pair as in .env file?

Comment: You probably either did not upload your *.env* file to the server or you put it in the wrong directory on the server.

Comment: ah.. found it. Thank you so much @KurtisRader :3